# Авторизация пользователя с логином и паролем на кириллице

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

На первый взгляд очень простая и глупая проблема. У пользователя в MS SQL Server хранится логин и пароль (Возможно в кириллице). Ни бд, ни entity framework не видит запись, когда я делаю выборку. К тому же, программа не видит разницы между строчными и прописными буквами - Qwerty и qwerty одно и тоже.

```
var user = App.db.User.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Login == this.tbLogin.Text && x.Password == this.tbPassword.Password);

if (user == null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Такого пользователя не существует", "Ошибка авторизации", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Но код программы вы нам не покажете, так? :)

Comment: @tym32167 Это пример с WPF, но в данном случае не играет роли

Comment: Профайлером поглядите запросы к БД, какой SQL выполняется при вашем запросе?

Comment: @tym32167 С первой проблемой разобрался,кодировка кривая. А вот другая осталось - регистр не учитывается

Comment: `Профайлером поглядите запросы к БД, какой SQL выполняется при вашем запросе?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это вызвано тем, что запросы на стороне SQL Server фильтруют данные с учетом текущего Collation для базы / таблицы / столбца.

## Решения правкой базы

#### Database First:

Можно поменять Collation ("Параметры сортировки"), или через редактор, или кодом:

```
ALTER TABLE Users ALTER COLUMN tbLogin VARCHAR(MAX) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS NOT NULL
```

Вместо `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS`  - стоит взять актуальный Collation, и заменить `_CI_` на `_CS_`.

#### Code First

Сделать то же самое, миграцией:

```
public override void Up()
{
   Sql("ALTER TABLE Users ALTER COLUMN tbLogin VARCHAR(MAX) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS NOT NULL");
}
```

Если нужно делать массово, для нескольких колонок - [использовать кастомную аннотацию](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29866328/1988244).

## Решение без правки базы

Просто повторить запрос дважды - сначала в базе, потом, для обеспечения case sensivity, в коде:

```
var user = App.db.User
    .Where(x => x.Login == this.tbLogin.Text && x.Password == this.tbPassword.Password)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Where(x => x.Login == this.tbLogin.Text && x.Password == this.tbPassword.Password)
    .FirstOrDefault(); // для наглядности, можно слить с Where
```

Comment: AsEnumerable обязательно указывать надо, верно?

Comment: @Ari100krat да, ради того, чтобы вытащить результаты запроса в память, и перейти от EF к Linq to objects.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 1):

Может кому пригодится. Я просто установил нужные параметры в параметрах сортировки[image: Для конкретного поля]